# what is remainder when $(((3!)^{5!})^{7!})^{9!...}$ is divided by 11

Tags: modular-arithmetic, factorial

$$(((3!)^{5!})^{7!})^{9!...}$$ when divided by 11 what will be the reminder?

Hint is appreciated

---

Sorry I do not know how to start this problem, so I have not shown my efforts!

Comment: Do you know of any tools for reducing a power modulo an integer?

Comment: @anon no I have no idea! :(

Comment: You've never seen [Fernat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) or [Euler's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) before? If not, where did you get the problem from? (Because certainly any class, notes or textbook would cover tools for how to solve this problem before giving it...)

Comment: What exactly do the "..." mean?

Comment: It's implying that the sequence of residues $3!$, $3!^{5!}$, $(3!^{5!})^{7!}$, $((3!^{5!})^{7!})^{9!}$, $\cdots$ stabilizes presumably. This should have been stated up-front in the question of course.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Now we see that $(3!, 11)=(6,11)=1$. Hence by Fermat's theorem we have $(3!)^{10}\equiv 1[11]$ and hence $(3!)^{10m}\equiv 1[11]$. Moreover $10$ divides $5!$ so that $(((3!)^{5!})^{7!})^{...}\equiv 1[11]$.

Required reminder is 1.

Answer (score 5):

$$(3!,11)=1$$  By Fermat's Little Theorem, $$3^{11-1}\equiv1\pmod{11}$$

and $10|5!$

Answer (score -1):

see, the above number can be written like this

$(3!)^{5!*7!*9!*\dots}$

first look at the power of 3!, it will be a number ending with a lot of zeroes
let that number be n
hence $n(\mod 10)=0$
$\implies n=10*k$, $k$ is a positive integer
Now,
we have to find $6^n (\mod 11)=$?

by applying Fermat's little theorem $6^{10}(\mod 11)=1$
$=R[(6^{10})^k/11]$
$=R[1^k/11]$
$=1$.